# Cheap indices in Europe

Tags: index-fund, europe

I have currently started investing and have access to the following markets:
Xetra, BCPP, RMS
I see many good indices like the DAX, but I have no more than 500eur allocated. I saw that there are ETFs that replicate these index funds like EXS1, does something like that make sense for a long term investor (5-10years?). Also I can't find any fees associated with DAX - is that the case? Do fractional indices even exist in europe (the documents related to these indices don't even mention the word 'fractional' nor 'fees')

Comment: You edits change the meaning of the question and make the answer unrelated to the question. I rolled back your edits, please ask a new question instead.

Comment: Yes I know, but stack exchange is setup so that if you don't edit your questions to make sense then it will ban you in a couple posts.

Answer (score 2):

You can’t buy an index. An index only gives you a value, which is a weighted average of the stocks it is composed of (each index having their own criteria for deciding which stocks it contains and the respecting weighting).

So there are obviously no fees for that since you can’t buy it, and no “fractional” indices.

What you can do is buy the right number of shares of each of the stocks in that index, but given the weights, you are probably going to have to buy A LOT to replicate the weights accurately. You would also need to track the changes in the stocks and their respective weights. Good luck with that.

Or you could buy shares in a fund which does exactly that. Details of the value of those shares and associated fees are specific to each of those.

Note that the criteria of the composition of an index are quite arbitrary, and do not necessarily align with whatever goals you may have. Other funds may have more specific strategies in term of risk and return profiles (as usual, the higher the promised return, the higher the risk). People usually will have a low of “safe” (but low return) and “high return” (but risky) investments. Where you place the cursor depends a lot on your circumstances.

Comment: Aha and so what is the way to find the best index fund/ETF tracking a particular index? What other funds track indices?

Comment: Index funds and ETFs are your choices. As far as picking the best one goes: Look at their history of how well they track the index they are following, and look for minimum fees (as discussed here recently). And remember that you may want to track a mix of indexes; the usual mix is long term, mid/short term, bonds, "income producing"  and international. How much of which... Again, see recent answers